# php show last user login timestamp from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I insert loggedin (timestamp) and loggedout (timestamp) into MySQL database for each user login and logout like this :

```
|  id   |   loggedout    |    loggedin    |     userid    |
| 220   |       0        |   1413752629   |      110      |
| 219   |   1413729139   |   1412794088   |      105      |
| 218   |   1413225014   |   1412794089   |      55       |
| 217   |   1412855149   |   1412794086   |      78       |
| 216   |   1412794081   |   1413224871   |      110      |
| 215   |   1412794086   |   1413729139   |      110      |
```

before user log out i set `0` for default loggedout value. this value worked for log in(online user). Now i need to print user loggedout value for last login Like This :

In Sample database Userid `110` loggedin now (id 220). now i need to print last login for userid `110`(id 216).

how do print output for show last login user date/time?!

**my mean IS**: when user log in to system i need to show last login time from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use this query:

```
SELECT loggedin FROM table_name WHERE userid = 110 AND loggedout != 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Hope it helped

Answer (score 2):

```
   SELECT MAX(loggedin)
     FROM tbl

    WHERE userid = 110
      AND loggedout != 0
```

Like this?

Comment: @zerkms: for retrieve value i have this line : `$lastlogin = $row['loggedin'];` but i see this error : `Notice: Undefined index: loggedin.` how do retrieve value `MAX(loggedin)`??

Comment: @None Coder: you give it an alias `SELECT MAX(loggedin) AS whateveryoulike` then you use that alias as a key